# I couldn't import/require react-component class inside a node_modules package on web development

Tags: import, reactjs, react-native, require, node-modules

my code is like:

```
import Render from './AppeRender';
import { Component } from  'react';
export default class appDB extends Component {
  render () {
    return Render.call(this, this.props, this.state);
  }
}
```

and what i'm getting is:
Module parse failed: /home/projects/node_modules/DB/Db.js Line 5:  Unexpected token 
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Note: Error only comes in web setup, it's working fine in android and in IOS i haven't tried yet.
Does anyone have any idea regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is wrong here is that you using `import` twice (and the second one is a destructure.

Try this instead:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import Render from './AppeRender';
```

You can bind `Component` in one import.

The second import *could* have been changed to a straight destructure:

```
const { Component } = React;
```

But, there is no reason to do this if you are only using `Component`.

Using `import` on an `Object` is not really correct (however, it might work with some implementations), I assume that is why the error was occurring.

Comment: You are right, we can destructure Component in same line (as i edited), but this also not working, i tried with require also but not hit the target :-(